# Vue: Not rendering the component for the second time on routing

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am facing behavior of Vue which I don't understand.  I am using routing between components.

```
   methods: {
        redirectToLogin() {
            this.$router.push("/login");
        },
        redirectToRegister() {
            this.$router.push("/register");
        }
    }
```

So when load the app, route Login component, login successfully and then log out to component with methods above. After this when I am trying to route to login again the Login component is not rendered, but the route is shown in the address line

Below you can see my routes

```
    routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'Hello', component: Hello},
    {path: "/login",name:'Login', component: Login},
    {path: "/register",name:'Register', component: Register},
    {path: "/user/:id",name:'User', component: User},
    {path: "/reset",name:'PasswordReset', component: PasswordReset},
  ]
```

I am also using Vuex can it somehow affect such behaviour?

UPD:

When I log out I see the following error in my console

> TypeError: "t._data is undefined"
>           VueJS 14
>               $destroy
>               destroy
>               _
>               T
>               x
>               $
>               ji
>               _update
>               r
>               get
>               run
>               Yn
>               he
>               ue
>       vue.runtime.esm.js:1888:12

UPD 2 : Components

This is first component loaded to the app. After logging out route leads here and none of the router links work

```
    export default {
        name: 'Hello',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Work With your projects in agile manner'
            }
        }
    }
```

Login component

```
export default {
    name: "Login",
    data() {
        return {
            errorOccurred: false,
            errorMessage: '',
            credentials: {
                login: '',
                password: ''
            },
            remember: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$store.dispatch('loginUser', this.credentials).then(() => {
                this.errorMessage = this.getError;
                if (this.errorMessage.length) {
                    this.errorOccurred = true;

                } else {
                    this.$router.push({path: '/user/' + this.getId});
                }
            });

            this.errorOccurred = false;
        },
        resetPassword() {
            this.$router.push("/reset");
        },
    },
    computed: {
        loginValidation() {
            return this.credentials.login.length > 0
        },
        passwordValidation() {
            return this.credentials.password.length > 0
        },
        getError() {
            return this.$store.getters.getErrorMsg;
        },
        getId() {
            return this.$store.getters.getUserId;
        }
    },
}
```

User component routed from login.

```
    import NavbarCommon from "./NavbarCommon";
    export default {
        name: "User",
        components: {NavbarCommon},
        data(){
        },
        methods: {
            loadAvatar(){
               let image = '../../assets/emptyAvatar.png';
                if ('avatar' in  this.getUser){
                    image = this.getUser.avatar;
                }

                return image;
            }
        },
        computed:{
            getUser() {
                    return this.$store.getters.getUser;
            }
        }
    }
```

And two two more components. 
NavbarComponent - common navbar for several components

```
    import NavbarRight from "./NavbarRight";
    export default {
        name: "NavbarCommon",
        components: {NavbarRight},
        methods:{
            routeToUser(){
                this.$router.push({path: '/user/' + this.getUser});
            },
            routeToProject(){
                this.$router.push({path: '/project/' + this.getProject});
            }
        },
        computed:{
            getUser() {
                return this.$store.getters.getUserId;
            },
            getProject(){
                //TODO:
                return 'get project id'
            }
        }
    }
```

And right part of Navbar with logout button

```
export default {
    name: "NavbarRight",
    methods:{
        logOut(){
            this.$store.dispatch('logOutUser').then(()=>{
                this.$router.push('/');
            });

        },

    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is valid and should work. What I suspect is that your component throws an error when Vue tries to run it - hence it does not render. Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @MarcRo , I see only an error from chunk.js which makes no sense to me

Comment: Chunk.js is most likely your component that won't render. Can you post the error?

Comment: @MarcRo check the update

Comment: Please also post the component. You should have some invalid code in a lifecycle hook

Comment: @MarcRo updated

Comment: I'm sorry but it is still not clear what is happening.  Please also provide the template of your Root and Hello component. Where are the two methods you posted first located? Your code above is once again valid and should work.

Comment: https://github.com/abondar24/WebScrumBoard you can check the code of ui here. There minor differences which are not commited(router links and place where routing from log out is done, but the issue still reproducible)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using  Store-Computed way of handling data fetching instead of using route guards such as beforeRouteEnter and beforeRouteUpdate? That way you can fire off methods when the route is hit.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is really stupid.

In User component data missed return.

After adding

```
data(){
        return {}
    },
```

Everything started working

Comment: Vue recursively converts the returned object into getter/setters to make it “reactive”. If you don't need `data`, remove it altogether. A shorthand of an empty `data` would be `data: () => ({})`. Point being: it has to be a function returning an object. [Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data).

Comment: I will need it later, the User component is far from being ready